# Alternative (python) to calculate distance between all points at two different sets

Tags: python, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have two different bunches of points: `set_1` and `set_2`.
Using python, I want to calculate all distances from points at `set_1` to points at `set_2`.

Poins are 1dimension arrays:

```
point_1=np.array([x1,y1,z1])
```

Sets of points are 2dimensional arrays:

```
set_1=np.array([[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2], ...[xn,yn,zn]])
```

Using `distance` from `scipy.spatial` this is my approach:

```
np.array([[distance.euclidean(i,j) for i in set_1] for j in set_2])
```

May I apply `distance.euclidean` directly somehow to `set_1` and `set_2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) is designed to do.

For example,

```
In [21]: import numpy as np

In [22]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

In [23]: set_1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2], [1, -1, 3]])

In [24]: set_2 = np.array([[0, 0, 10], [1, 1, 1]])

In [25]: cdist(set_1, set_2)
Out[25]: 
array([[10.        ,  1.73205081],
       [ 8.1240384 ,  1.        ],
       [ 7.14142843,  2.82842712]])
```